# SQL Server Database Backup Size Variation

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups, backup-strategies

When I did a database backup a day before yesterday, it was 413 MB big. When I did it yesterday, the size was 389 MB. When I run the backup today, the size is about 452 MB. What is the reason for the variation on database backup size?

Comment: Is the amount of data in the DB constant?

Comment: The backup size may vary due to the number of used pages, compression, and the portion of the transaction log included to recover the database to a consistent state.